# F#: How to match on a substring?

Tags: f#, match

I am new to F#, but not new to programming. Most of my experience is in the C# and SQL world. MSDN and other sites I've looked at haven't quite made this simple enough for my little brain yet, so I'm wondering if you can give me a nudge in the right direction.

I'm trying to write a simple function that returns true if a string is null, empty, or starts with "//", else it should return false.

```
#light

let thisIsACommentOrBlank line =
    match line with
    | null -> true
    | "" -> true
    | notSureWhatToPutHere -> true
    | _ -> false
```

Thanks!

**Update**

Thanks to all of your suggestions, in the end, I was able to collapse everything down to a lambda as follows:

```
|> List.filter (fun line -> not (System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("//")))
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Just a comment ;) You don't need the #light directive anymore.

Comment: You mean it's time to take the training wheels off?

Comment: Haha - yes. Its been like that for quite some time now. #light syntax is default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
let thisIsACommentOrBlank line =
    match line with
    | a when System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a) || a.StartsWith("//") -> true
    | _ -> false;;
```

Comment: Awesome. For some reason I was having trouble getting IsNullOrWhiteSpace and StartsWith working in F# in my earlier attempts, but this clearly works! Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit verbose – `let thisIsACommentOrBlank line = System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("//")` would do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `when` clause, like this:

```
let thisIsACommentOrBlank line =
    match line with
    | null -> true
    | "" -> true
    | s when s.StartsWith "//" -> true
    | _ -> false
```

But for that matter, this is a lot simpler:

```
let thisIsACommentOrBlank line = 
    (String.IsNullOrEmpty line) || (line.StartsWith "//")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just omit last match:

```
let thisIsACommentOrBlank line =
    match line with
    | null -> true
    | "" -> true
    | s -> s.StartsWith "//"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *when condition* (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx)):

```
let thisIsACommentOrBlank line =
    match line with
    | null -> true
    | "" -> true
    | s when s.StartsWith "//" -> true
    | _ -> false
```

But your function can be optimized:

```
let thisIsACommentOrBlank = function
| null | "" -> true
| s -> s.StartsWith "//"
```